# build CDT source code with m2eclipse

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

all,

I am trying to build one of CDT plugin and export it independently. For example, I built "org.eclipse.cdt.ui" plugin, and then I got the following built error message:

Project has not been setup yet MavenProject: org.eclipse.cdt:org.eclipse.cdt.ui:5.5.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Documents and Settings\0359\workspace\org.eclipse.cdt\core\org.eclipse.cdt.ui\pom.xml   org.eclipse.cdt.ui      line 1  Maven Problem

I am headless with this problem, any suggestion is good. thanks.

its pom.xml is as following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.cdt</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdt-parent</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<version>5.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<artifactId>org.eclipse.cdt.ui</artifactId>
<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
< /project>
```

Comment: Do you have a <project> element in your POM file?

Comment: @ChetterHummin: yes. everything was downloaded from Eclipse.org Git repositories. I hadn't modified them yet.

Comment: where is the dependency in your pom.xml?